# help running opencv on android

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I'm trying to run this opencv sample for android from here.
http://code.google.com/p/android-opencv/

I've followed the instructions very closely and successfully built opencv and then CVCamera from the samples. I then setup opencv as an android library project and referenced it from CVCamera.

When I install the app on to the emulator and run it, I don't get any errors. The app focuses and immediately loses focus and seems to terminate. Here are the DDMS messages. Any idea why it might not be working?

```
01-09 07:36:32.503: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/.CVCamera }
01-09 07:36:32.593: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Start proc com.theveganrobot.cvcamera for activity com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/.CVCamera: pid=230 uid=10024 gids={1006, 1015}
01-09 07:36:32.913: DEBUG/ddm-heap(230): Got feature list request
01-09 07:36:32.983: INFO/WindowManager(53): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=0
01-09 07:36:33.073: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=18}
01-09 07:36:33.363: DEBUG/dalvikvm(230): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so 0x43d0bb68
01-09 07:36:33.493: INFO/DEBUG(28): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-09 07:36:33.503: INFO/DEBUG(28): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.1-update1/ECLAIR/35983:eng/test-keys'
01-09 07:36:33.503: INFO/DEBUG(28): pid: 230, tid: 230  >>> com.theveganrobot.cvcamera <<<
01-09 07:36:33.503: INFO/DEBUG(28): signal 4 (SIGILL), fault addr 80d763a4
01-09 07:36:33.503: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r0 00000000  r1 80e0cbb8  r2 80ca9199  r3 80cb1839
01-09 07:36:33.503: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r4 000efdf0  r5 80e6fa24  r6 00000004  r7 00000000
01-09 07:36:33.503: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r8 ad00f380  r9 0000bd00  10 4104bbe8  fp 00000000
01-09 07:36:33.503: INFO/DEBUG(28):  ip 80e66208  sp becb4600  lr 80ca94c7  pc 80d763a4  cpsr 60000030
01-09 07:36:33.603: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #00  pc 001763a4  /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so
01-09 07:36:33.603: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #01  pc 000a94c2  /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so
01-09 07:36:33.613: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #02  pc b00001fc  /system/bin/linker
01-09 07:36:33.613: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #03  pc b00002bc  /system/bin/linker
01-09 07:36:33.613: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #04  pc b00018a4  /system/bin/linker
01-09 07:36:33.624: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #05  pc b0001b70  /system/bin/linker
01-09 07:36:33.624: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #06  pc b0001552  /system/bin/linker
01-09 07:36:33.624: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #07  pc b0001cbc  /system/bin/linker
01-09 07:36:33.624: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #08  pc 0003cdfc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.624: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #09  pc 0005416a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.634: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #10  pc 00013f58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.644: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #11  pc 00019888  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.644: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #12  pc 00018d5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.644: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #13  pc 0004d6d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.644: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #14  pc 0004d702  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.654: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #15  pc 00058232  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.654: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #16  pc 00059ab4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.664: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #17  pc 00010fe8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.674: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #18  pc 00019888  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.674: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #19  pc 00018d5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.683: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #20  pc 0004d6d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.683: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #21  pc 0004d702  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.683: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #22  pc 00053ce4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.694: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #23  pc 00013f58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.694: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #24  pc 00019888  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.703: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #25  pc 00018d5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.703: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #26  pc 0004d3bc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.703: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #27  pc 00054e74  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.703: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #28  pc 00013f58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.703: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #29  pc 00019888  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.714: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #30  pc 00018d5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.734: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #31  pc 0004d6d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-09 07:36:33.734: INFO/DEBUG(28): code around pc:
01-09 07:36:33.734: INFO/DEBUG(28): 80d76394 b08bb530 46054c10 20009306 bf009b10 
01-09 07:36:33.734: INFO/DEBUG(28): 80d763a4 0c00f20f 44649000 f04f9003 93090c28 
01-09 07:36:33.734: INFO/DEBUG(28): 80d763b4 90029b0e f8cd4668 9307c004 91049b0f 
01-09 07:36:33.734: INFO/DEBUG(28): code around lr:
01-09 07:36:33.734: INFO/DEBUG(28): 80ca94b4 480f1861 58e318a2 90021820 f0cc4628 
01-09 07:36:33.734: INFO/DEBUG(28): 80ca94c4 4b0cff67 58e14628 58e24b0b ec24f7b1 
01-09 07:36:33.734: INFO/DEBUG(28): 80ca94d4 bd30b005 001bccfc ffe445c1 00000264 
01-09 07:36:33.744: INFO/DEBUG(28): stack:
01-09 07:36:33.744: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45c0  b000fd00  /system/bin/linker
01-09 07:36:33.744: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45c4  80e660c0  /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so
01-09 07:36:33.744: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45c8  00000000  
01-09 07:36:33.780: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45cc  b0000559  /system/bin/linker
01-09 07:36:33.784: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45d0  0000001b  
01-09 07:36:33.784: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45d4  aca01df2  /system/lib/libGLESv2.so
01-09 07:36:33.784: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45d8  b00163f8  
01-09 07:36:33.784: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45dc  b00032e8  /system/bin/linker
01-09 07:36:33.784: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45e0  b00129d8  
01-09 07:36:33.784: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45e4  becb45fc  [stack]
01-09 07:36:33.784: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45e8  80c3b080  /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so
01-09 07:36:33.784: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45ec  b000fac4  /system/bin/linker
01-09 07:36:33.794: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45f0  afe42c7c  
01-09 07:36:33.794: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45f4  afe0f3b0  /system/lib/libc.so
01-09 07:36:33.794: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45f8  df002777  
01-09 07:36:33.794: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb45fc  e3a070ad  
01-09 07:36:33.794: INFO/DEBUG(28): #00 becb4600  00000000  
01-09 07:36:33.794: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4604  afe0f2c0  /system/lib/libc.so
01-09 07:36:33.794: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4608  00000000  
01-09 07:36:33.794: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb460c  00000001  
01-09 07:36:33.794: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4610  00001000  
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4614  80c5bbdc  /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4618  80caa5a1  /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb461c  afe23043  /system/lib/libc.so
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4620  00000000  
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4624  afe179a5  /system/lib/libc.so
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4628  00000000  
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb462c  80e66198  /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4630  80e6fa24  
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4634  80ca94c7  /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28): #01 becb4638  80caa759  /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb463c  80ca91bd  /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4640  80cb1839  /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4644  80e63bf8  /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4648  00000004  
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb464c  80e63bfc  /data/data/com.theveganrobot.cvcamera/lib/libandroid-opencv.so
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4650  00000003  
01-09 07:36:33.804: INFO/DEBUG(28):     becb4654  b00001ff  /system/bin/linker
01-09 07:36:34.454: DEBUG/Zygote(30): Process 230 terminated by signal (4)
01-09 07:36:34.454: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Process com.theveganrobot.cvcamera (pid 230) has died.
01-09 07:36:34.514: INFO/ARMAssembler(53): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00000004_00000000 [ 22 ipp] (41 ins) at [0x48c470:0x48c514] in 13459425 ns
01-09 07:36:34.644: DEBUG/dalvikvm(53): GC freed 4974 objects / 263544 bytes in 145ms
01-09 07:36:34.654: INFO/WindowManager(53): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=0
01-09 07:36:34.704: INFO/ActivityManager(53): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=18}
01-09 07:36:34.814: INFO/UsageStats(53): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.theveganrobot.cvcamera
01-09 07:36:34.894: WARN/InputManagerService(53): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43cb43c8
01-09 07:36:37.094: DEBUG/dalvikvm(53): GC freed 1944 objects / 103176 bytes in 78ms
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem... it seems to be a bug. Here's the link to the ticket

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/789

The error occurs for me only when using the Emulator. If you try loading and running on the device directly, it might work

Comment: Damn. I need this very quick. Do you know of a workaround or an earlier version which does not have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

SIGILL means that your program is trying to execute illegal instructions. In this case, the problem is that the emulator (as well as older devices) can only execute instructions from the ARMv5 ISA, while to gain better performance, we usually want things like OpenCV to be compiled against the ARMv7 ISA, which comes with an FPU. More info about this issue in this thread:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/a19fc6df3d661d79

To solve this, you need to recompile OpenCV without using any of the "v7" things from the NDK.